# Get All Text Nodes Which Actually Display

Tags: javascript, dom

I try to get all text nodes which actually display within the body of an HTML file. Namely, I want to get all text nodes which follow the rule of `innerText` (except the text nodes within `<script>`, `<style>` and **hidden with CSS**). I have tried to use `createTreeWalker` with `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT` to get all text nodes as following mentioned.

```js
let textNodeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.body,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT
)
let textNodeList = []
while (textNodeWalker.nextNode()) textNodeList.push(textNodeWalker.currentNode)
```

However, this would return all text nodes including those would not show on the monitor. I also have tried to use `document.body.innerText` but this would not give me a list of DOM nodes rather than generate a plain text string. Is it possible to get all text nodes (returning an array) which follow the rule of [`innerText`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp)?

Comment: Something like `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("body *")).filter(n => n.innerText && n.tagName != "SCRIPT" && n.tagName != "STYLE")`? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7a8Lz4ft/

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much.